# Communication between main and render processes

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am tracking mouse coordinates inside my renderer side. What I want to achieve is, I will send these changing mouse coordinates to a function in main.js (node.js), then this function will calculate something and return value and my other function in renderer will use this variable like a ping pong.

This process will be repeated every time when the user moves the mouse. Is this possible with **electron.js**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but better to do function with mouse coordinates in the renderer side. because sending ipc messages like a stream may slow down the application.

Following is an example how you can use ipc messages for this purpose.

```
(function() {


    const ipcRenderer = require('electron').ipcRenderer;
    document.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        var eventDoc, doc, body;

        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism

        // If pageX/Y aren't available and clientX/Y are,
        // calculate pageX/Y - logic taken from jQuery.
        // (This is to support old IE)
        if (event.pageX == null && event.clientX != null) {
            eventDoc = (event.target && event.target.ownerDocument) || document;
            doc = eventDoc.documentElement;
            body = eventDoc.body;

            event.pageX = event.clientX +
              (doc && doc.scrollLeft || body && body.scrollLeft || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientLeft || body && body.clientLeft || 0);
            event.pageY = event.clientY +
              (doc && doc.scrollTop  || body && body.scrollTop  || 0) -
              (doc && doc.clientTop  || body && body.clientTop  || 0 );
        }

        // Use event.pageX / event.pageY here
        ipcRenderer.send('mouse-move',{ x : event.pageX , y : event.pageY });
    }
})();
```

and in the main.js

```
const ipcMain= require('electron').ipcMain;
ipcMain.on('mouse-move', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints eg :"{ x: 0 , y : 0 }"
  event.sender.send('return-value', arg.x + arg.y);//for eg : adds x and y
})
```

and catch the return value in the renderer script

```
ipcRenderer.on('return-value', (event, arg) => {
  console.log(arg) // prints 0 ; x + y 
  // Do what you want to do with the value
})
```

Comment: how can I embed my main.js code in browser? I mean should I write all the "require's that my node.js npms required for main.js calculation inside browser html? thank you for the reply. If I can do this problem would be really solved. I can send you the file if you help me it will be really appreciated.

Comment: I get this error message from the main: A Javascript errror occurred in the main process. Uncaught exception: TypeError: event.reply is not a function at EventEmitter.ipcMain.on

Answer (score 1):

Read the topic **ipc communication** i.e. [IpcMain](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-main) & [IpcRenderer](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/ipc-renderer).

by using ipc communication mechanism you can setup communication between main and renderer process.